# Spring 6 and Jersey 3 -> 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey, spring-jersey

I am migrating from Spring 5 to Spring 6.0.13 and I am having problem with Jersey 3.1.1.

In WebInitializer :

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        var webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.register(this.createContextConfig());
        webApplicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webApplicationContext));

        var dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic theDispatcherServlet  =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
        theDispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        theDispatcherServlet.addMapping("/*");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic jerseyRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("jerseyServlet",
                "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer");
        jerseyRegistration.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", RestApplication.class.getName());
        jerseyRegistration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                JerseyGsonProvider.class.getPackageName());
        jerseyRegistration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", "true");
        jerseyRegistration.addMapping("/rest/*");
        jerseyRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
   }

  ....
}
```

RestApplication:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestApplication() {
        registerClasses(FooResource.class);
        register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.global.getLogger("JerseyLogger"),
                Level.FINE, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 8192));
        System.out.println("CLASSES REGISTERED IN JERSEY");//THIS MESSAGE IS NEVER PRINTED
    }
}
```

FooResource:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/temp")
    public String temp() {
        return "<body>Hello! This is temp rest</body>";
    }

}
```

And when I open http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/foo/temp I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    /rest/foo/temp
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    jerseyServlet
Powered by Jetty:// 12.0.3
```

Log:

```
jakarta.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at jersey.server@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:258) [jersey-server-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.common@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265) [jersey-common-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.server@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:240) [jersey-server-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.server@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697) [jersey-server-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.container.servlet.core@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.container.servlet.core@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.container.servlet.core@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:357) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.container.servlet.core@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at jersey.container.servlet.core@3.1.1/org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.1.1.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1370) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:736) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.websocket.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:195) [jetty-ee10-websocket-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1581) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$MappedServlet.handle(ServletHandler.java:1542) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.dispatch(ServletChannel.java:886) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.handle(ServletChannel.java:491) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:463) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:571) [jetty-security-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:693) [jetty-ee10-servlet-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:809) [jetty-server-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179) [jetty-server-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:649) [jetty-server-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:471) [jetty-server-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322) [jetty-io-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100) [jetty-io-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53) [jetty-io-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:971) [jetty-util-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1196) [jetty-util-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util@12.0.3/org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1151) [jetty-util-12.0.3.jar:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: Spring 6 is JakartaEE make sure you are using a compatible Jersey version and that your configuration has been changed as well. The `javax.ws.rs.Application` looks wrong and I think needs to be `jakarta.ws.rs.Application` nowaways. I would suggest finding an upgrade guide for Jersey from JavaEE to JakartaEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 6 is JakartaEE based (and not JavaEE) based. As the application does start without warning/error about non found classes/incompatible classes I assume the version of Jersey used is compatible with JakartaEE.

However your configuration still reflects the old JavaEE configuration.

```
jerseyRegistration.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", RestApplication.class.getName());
```

Should be

```
jerseyRegistration.setInitParameter("jakarta.ws.rs.Application", RestApplication.class.getName());
```

That should get you started. You also might want to checkout the [Jersey Migration Guide](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/migration.html) which mentions this briefly as well as other things that have changed and might impact you.